# Juniper filter OSPF type-7 routes on ABR

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

Somebody knows why NSSA external routes filtering on ABR is so unuseful on JunOS?

For example I want to filter all routes coming from NSSA area 0.0.0.3 except "10.0.0.0/8 orlonger" routes. To do that I must enter those commands:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 128.0.0.0/1 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 64.0.0.0/2 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 32.0.0.0/3 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 16.0.0.0/4 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 0.0.0.0/5 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 12.0.0.0/6 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 8.0.0.0/7 restrict
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.3 nssa area-range 11.0.0.0/8 restrict
```

Maybe someone knows a more straightforward way to accomplish this task on JunOS?

Comment: Is there a reason you are exporting these extra routes you don't need into the NSSA in the first place? Perhaps a tighter export policy on the ASBR will solve this? Unless of course you need reachability within area 3.